# AngularJS filter JSON object {} that is not an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I am trying to apply a filter to a JSON object without much luck.

The data structure is something like this:

```
$scope.jsonObj = {
    someid8979: {
        name: "Bill",
        age: 18
    },
    someid987: {
        name: "Ted",
        age: 17
    }
}
```

In my HTML, something like this:

```
<input ng-model="search">
<div ng-repeat="(key,val) in jsonObj | filter:search">
    {{key}} - {{val.name}} - {{val.age}}
</div>
```

In the past, I have always sent out the data as an array of objects, and indeed, if I did that here it would work, but due to the nature of the app, this isn't possible as I need to refer to properties on the object by name (the id) elsewhere in the code.

Is there any way to apply a filter to a JSON object similar to this?

I could create a separate array just for filtering purposes and target the JSON object for my other actions, but I'd rather not :)

**Edit:** I made a duplicate of the object as array and looped over that, which allows filtering. This solves my problem, but not in the way I had hoped. Could be good enough.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887504/filtering-on-object-map-rather-than-array-in-angularjs

Comment: Yes, as I stated, it can be done with an array, I am just wondering if possible with an object. Thanks, though.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filter.js#L118 So `filter` only works with arrays.

Comment: @ Konstantin Krass Could you share how to do this? This doesn't work out of the box. Angular docs state clearly that filter accepts an array https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 0):

You could place the comparator function in your controller like in this plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/n93RjIqLehVymmjjbTQd?p=preview

Comment: My model is not an array. The built-in $filter expects an array. I am just curious if there is a solution that can use an object. Not an array. {} vs. [].