# Filter an object by keys inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want exclude the other items that are not listed to defaults but it still show every items

```
<ul ng-controller="Ctrl" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in Employee.KeyValue | filter:DefaultKeys(key) ">{{key}}</li>
</ul>

angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.DefaultKeys = function(item) {
        var defaultItems = ["SSS No.", "TIN"];

        return defaultItems.indexOf(item);
    };

    $scope.Employee =
        {
            Code: '123',            
            KeyValue:
            {
                'TIN': '9038468',
                'Facebook' : 'https://fb.com/abc'
            }
        }
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e06x7efh/1/)

Any help please

Comment: can't use `filter` on objects, only arrays. You will have to do it in controller instead

Comment: ooohhh.. i see.. thanks charlietfl

Comment: Here is a similar question to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887504/filtering-on-object-map-rather-than-array-in-angularjs.
I hope you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom filter.

**Filter**

```
angular.module('app', []).filter('DefaultKeys', function () {
    return function (item) {
        var keys = {};
        angular.forEach(['SSS No.', 'TIN'], function (key) {
            if (item[key] !== undefined) {
                keys[key] = item[key];
            }
        });
        return keys;
    };
});
```

**Html**

```
<ul ng-controller="Ctrl" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in Employee.KeyValue | DefaultKeys">{{key}}</li>
</ul>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e06x7efh/18/)**</kbd>