# ngRepeat treats an array-like object as an object not an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have something called NoDupesArray. I used it to create an array that doesn't allow duplicated items in it. Programmatically, it's an object that extends the Array prototype like the following (let's not argue over Object.create vs this):

```
function NoDupesArray(){}
NoDupesArray.prototype = Array.prototype
NoDupesArray.prototype.push = function(){
    //...blahblahblha
}
```

Unfortunately, when I use this array in ng-repeat in Angular, I can't use Angular's built in filter feature. This does not work:

```
<li class="row" ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter:{completed_at:'!null'}"></li>
```

I assume this is because angular is treating "tasks" as an object instead of an array. Is there a way to force angular to recognize my custom array as an array so I can use the filters? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So for now the solution I'm using is:

```
<li class="row" ng-repeat="task in tasks.slice() | filter:{completed_at:'!null'}"></li>
```

This turns the NoDupesArray back into a plain old array but I figure there has to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If tasks is an Object you can still use ng-repeat. You should provide two variables for the values and the keys in the object like this:

```
<li class="row" ng-repeat="(key, task) in tasks | filter:{completed_at:'!null'}"></li>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that code doesn't work. Looks like filterFilter just returns the array unfiltered if it doesn't think it's an array even if it is. Friend found this for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887504/filtering-on-object-map-rather-than-array-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Maintain the original functionality of Array.push()

```
NoDupesArray.prototype.push = function (){
  return function() {
    var uniqueArguments = getItemsNotInArray(this, arguments);
    return Array.prototype.push.apply(this, uniqueArguments);
  };
};
```

Comment: Yeah that's the body of the function. The issue seems to be that angular doesn't use instanceof to check if NoDupesArray is an array or an object.