# Can query values with ng-repeat, but can't apply filter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a MongoDB with a list of objects as structured below:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("11122223333"),
    "name" : "Bob",
    "availability" : "Availabile",
    "toolcap" : {
        "toolAA" : {
            "skill" : "certified",
            "tool" : "tool1",
            "caps" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "cap1",
                    "expertise" : "pro"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "cap2",
                    "expertise" : "pro"
                }
            ]
        },
        "toolBB" : {
            "skill" : "certified",
            "tool" : "tool2",
            "caps" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "cap3",
                    "expertise" : "semi-pro"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "cap4",
                    "expertise" : "novice"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "local" : {
        "password" : "password123",
        "email" : "bob@email.com",
        "name" : "Bob"
    }
}
```

I ng-repeat through this data for every object in the collection (the rest of the table not shown):

```html
<tr ng-repeat-start="x in users | filter:{'name':'Bob'}:true" ng-if="false"></tr>
<tr ng-repeat-start="y in x.toolcap" ng-if="false"></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="z in y.caps">
  <td>{{y.tool}}</td>
  <td>{{z.name}}</td>
  <td>{{z.expertise}}</td>
  <td>{{x.availability}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="false"></tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="false"></tr>
```

This renders fine - I can filter by name, and related values go into the same row. The problem I'm encountering is when I try to filter by "tool", for example, wanting to see things associated with only "tool1" ("tool1" MUST exist, otherwise don't give me back a row. The same way name:Bob MUST exist). I thought I could do the following on line 2 to only see things associated with "tool1":

```html
<tr ng-repeat-start="x in users | filter:{'name':'Bob'}:true" ng-if="false"></tr>
<tr ng-repeat-start="y in x.toolcap | filter:{'tool':'tool1'"}:true" ng-if="false"></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="z in y.caps">
  <td>{{y.tool}}</td>
  <td>{{z.name}}</td>
  <td>{{z.expertise}}</td>
  <td>{{x.availability}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="false"></tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="false"></tr>
```

Regardless of what I put into that new filter, I get back every thing. I would expect the table to be as follows (columns separated by commas):

row1: tool1, cap1, pro, available
row2: tool1, cap2, pro, available

But instead I get the same thing as my first html snippet:

row1: tool1, cap1, pro, available
row2: tool1, cap2, pro, available
row3: tool2, cap3, semi-pro, available
row4: tool2, cap4, novice, available

I can, however, filter at the "expertise" level (only create new rows when expertise is "pro", for example). I've also tried applying the filter at different levels (each "tr"), at the "td" level, using x.tool instead of just tool, etc.

Comment: i guess its becuase of `ng-if` priority, try replacing ng-if with ng-show

Comment: indeed what do all these `ng-if="false"` are for? They will prevent anything to be displayed. And be careful you have an extra doublequote in your expression `{'tool':'tool1'"}` <- here

Comment: The quote was a mistake I made only in this version of the code.

Comment: You cannot use filter as-is since it only works with arrays and you have an object there. You need to change your data to array or use a custom filter. Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887504/filtering-on-object-map-rather-than-array-in-angularjs

Comment: Create your own filter to manage your own datas.