# angular filter on an object property in ngRepeat doesn't seem to work with 'track by'

Tags: angularjs

I have an map of data items I'm displaying in a table that gets refreshed with new values in the controller (hence the track by key).  This all works fine.

If I try to throw an angular filter into the mix, it ignores the filter and displays all the data.

(BTW, items in data are being filled in by a callback from data coming from websocket - maybe this is causing the problem)

What am I missing here?

```
<label>Filter by Id <input ng-model="search.id"></label><br>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>type</th>
        <th>value</th>
        <th>time</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in data | filter:search track by item.key">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.type}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value}}</td>
        <td>{{item.timestamp}}</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

controller:

```
            DataService.addListener(listener);

            $scope.data = {};
            //incoming data from a websocket
            function listener(data) {
                    var key =  data.stuff.id1 + ':' + data.stuff.id2;
                    var lineItem = {
                        'id' : data.stuff.id1,
                        'type' : data.stuff.id2,
                        'value' : data.data.value,
                        'timestamp' : new Date(data.stuff.ts).toTimeString(),
                        'key' :key
                    };

                   $scope.$apply(function() {
                        $scope.data[key] = lineItem;
                    });

                }
```

note that item.key is a property that uniquely identifies the item in the map of data.

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/tCQ7lGsx3n6PsDBrnW0P?p=preview. Try producing a plunker which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was filter doesn't work on maps.  Derp.

Stole a map filter from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24105038/4674479), now it all works.

plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/u5D3tGGKDOY4P4u6T1GZ?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="TestCtrl">

    <label>Filter by Id <input ng-model="search.id"></label><br>

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>value</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in data | mapFilter:search track by item.key">
            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
            <td>{{item.value}}</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

script:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      var item = {
        id: randomWord() + " " + randomWord(),
        key: 'key ' + i,
        value:  Math.floor(Math.random() * 300),
      };
      $scope.data[item.key] = item;
    }
})
.filter('mapFilter', function($filter) {
  var filter = $filter('filter');

  return function(map, expression, comparator) {
    if (! expression) return map;

    var result = {};
    angular.forEach(map, function(data, index) {
      if (filter([data], expression, comparator).length)
        result[index] = data;          
    });

    return result;
  }
});
var words = [
'lunville',
'pandybat',
'demurrer',
'slighter',
'reguline',
'exploder',
'krakatoa',
'wirespun',
  ];
function randomWord() {
  return words[ Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering by `search` and not `search.id` since your input's model is set as `search.id`. Try this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data | filter:search.id track by item.key">
```

Comment: I tried your code and it does not work.  the angular tutorial uses filter:search and JB Nizet's plunkr uses it too and it works fine.  thanks though